# Adding HashSet/Array to HashMap error

Tags: java, hashmap

I am a beginner at Java, and I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting an error. I have a .csv file containing cities, provinces, and respective populations of Canada. I have been trying to read the file and then put the PROVINCE and POPULATION values into a HashMap (cana) via a key/value pair. I've created a HashSet (canada) to split up the .csv, and I would like to keep that as-is if possible.

My question is about the cana.add(provSet, pop1). I am getting an "cannot find symbol - method add(java.util.Set) error around the "put", and I can't figure out why. Can someone please help me understand what I've done wrong? Since I am a beginner, additional explanation would be greatly appreciated!

```
String filename = "canada.csv";
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("canada.csv"));
        String line = null;
        HashSet<String> canada = new HashSet<String>();
        HashMap<Set<String>, Set<Integer>> cana = new HashMap<Set<String>, Set<Integer>>();


        while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {               

            String city = line.split(",")[0];
                canada.add(city);

            String province = line.split(",")[1];
                canada.add(province);
                Set<String> provSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(province));

            String population = line.split(",")[2];
                canada.add(population);
                int p = new Integer(population);
                Set<Integer> pop1 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(p));                             

            cana.add(provSet, pop1);    //ERROR                     

            //Trying to find the most populated province
            String maxProvince = "";
            int maxProvPop = 0;
            for(String province : cana.keySet()) {
              int provPop = cana.get(province);
              System.out.println(population);
                if( provPop > maxProvPop ) 
                {
                    maxProvPop = provPop;
                    maxProvince = province;
                }
                System.out.println("The most populated province is " + maxProvince + " with a population of " + maxProvPop);
            }
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need `put` instead of `add`... your description sounds like you know it *should* be `put`...

Comment: In your IDE, it will show you the available methods so you don't have to remember them for different collection types.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you will probably found the answer doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up the methods for `HashSet` and `HashMap`.  You use the `add` method for `HashSet`, and `put` method for `HashMap`.

[HashSet Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E))

[HashMap Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)